# Changing the values of a php class using a function

Tags: php, function, class

What i am trying to do is, change the value of what the following variables will give out.For example i have car 1 and its first three properties will be fixed such as the kind of car, colour and its ID/name but what i want to do is give a list of other values that the armour,wheels,engine and doors can be randomly changed to each time the page is refreshed.I will put my code in below thanks and sorry if i am un-clear, i will have a list of what each of the random values can be so please any help will be greatly appreciated!! thanks!

```
<?php

class car_1
{
    //fixed//
    public $id;
    public $color;
    public $type;
    //fixed//

    //need these to change//
    public $armour;
    public $wheels;
    public $engine;
    public $doors;


    public function __construct($id, $colour, $type, $armour, $wheels, $engine, $doors)
    {
        $this->id     = $id;
        $this->color  = $colour;
        $this->type   = $type;
        $this->armour = $armour;
        $this->wheels = $wheels;
        $this->engine = $engine;
        $this->doors  = $doors;
    }


    public function Action()
    {
        return "I'am ".

        $this->id."<br> My colour is ".
        $this->color."<br> My Armour is at = ".
        $this->armour."<br> I'am a ".
        $this->type." car. <br> I have ".
        $this->wheels." Wheels.<br> My Engine level is at ".
        $this->engine."<br> I have ".
        $this->doors." doors";


    }
}


$car1 = new car_1('Car 1', 'Red', 'Sports', '60%', '4', '2500', '3');
$car2 = new car_1('Car 2', 'Blue', 'Convertible', '70%', '4', '1500', '5');
$car3 = new car_1('Car 3', 'Green', 'Sports', '50%', '4', '1800', '3');
$car4 = new car_1('Car 4', 'Yellow', 'Off-Road', '60%', '3', '1300', '3');
$car5 = new car_1('Car 5', 'Orange', 'Saloon', '80%', '4', '2000', '5');
$car6 = new car_1('Car 6', 'Gold', 'Super', '100%', '4', '2000', '5');

echo "<p class=\"red\">".$car1->Action()."</p>";
echo "<p class=\"blue\">".$car2->Action()."</p>";
echo "<p class=\"green\">".$car3->Action()."</p>";
echo "<p class=\"yellow\">".$car4->Action()."</p>";
echo "<p class=\"black\">".$car5->Action()."</p>";
echo "<p class=\"gold\">".$car6->Action()."</p>";

?>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems like you need this, not that what you have described:

```
$my_array = array("a", "b", "c", "d", "e", "f", "g", "h", "i", "j", "k", "l", "m", "n", "o", "p", "0", "1", "2", "3", "4", "5");
$car1->armour = array_rand($my_array);
```

Comment: Hi thanks, took me a while but that was the right direction to go in, any idea how to display the actual value and the the key number?